# Dimension of pseudo holomorphic sections of a line bundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Given a Kaehler manifold $X$ and a complex line bundle $L\rightarrow X$, we say a connection $A$ on $L$ induces a holomorphic structure if $F_A^{2,0}=0$. In this case, the space of holomorphic sections of $L$, given by the kernel of $\overline{\partial}_A=pr^{0,1}\circ \nabla_A$ is finite dimensional, and the dimension does not depend on the connection $A$.

Now let $X$ be just a symplectic manifold endowed with an (non-integrable) almost complex structure. Given some connection $A$ on $L$, we can still define the operator $\overline{\partial}_A=pr^{0,1}\circ \nabla_A$.

Do we have similar results here, i.e. is the kernel still finite dimensional and does the dimension depend on the connection?

Comment: Where is the first part from? Im just curious.